# Teradata SQL - Split string, string has column name and value

Tags: sql, teradata

In table t1, I have colon delimited values like this

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | animal:horse |
| 2 | animal:cow |
| 3 | bird:parrot |
| 4 | bird:sparrow |

The requirement is the output to be in this format

| ID | animal | bird |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | horse |  |
| 2 | cow |  |
| 3 |  | parrot |
| 4 |  | sparrow |

Comment: Is this what you want? `select 
nvp(value, 'animal', ';', ':') as animal, nvp(value, 'bird', ';', ':') as bird from mytable`

Comment: @dnoeth . . . That should be an answer, not a comment.